# My armature does not appear

Tags: armature

[image]

So, I a trying to make a snowman's arms and body move, but suddenly, my armature does not appear anymore, it happened randonly, and I cant discover what caused the problem...
All armatures are supposed to appear within the scene

Comment: Please share your Blender file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there so that we can have a look and see what's going on..

Comment: Have you activated the local view? (menu > *View > Local View > Toggle Local View*, shortcut "Numpad /"). -- Another thing: If you have one model (snowman) you only need one armature for it. All bones including arms should be in this armature. If you want to add a bone make sure the armature is in *Edit* mode. Otherwise, you will create another armature with a single bone in *Object* mode. This is not what you want.

Comment: Oh, and you have turned off the *[Viewport Overlays](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html)* in your screenshot. That's why I cannot tell if you're in local view (the text on the top left of the viewport is hidden) - But if you turn the overlays off then this also *hides the bones* (and the selection, floor grid, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the top left of the viewport and turn on viewport overlays.
[image: do this]